# WSO2 File download over HTTP and save it to folder

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

How to create Proxy Service which is capable to download XML file from specific address and save it to the Folder?

I tried below answer : But it is not working VFS throws error :

```
     <call>
        <endpoint>
           <address format="soap11"
                    uri="https://scsanctions.un.org/resources/xml/en/consolidated.xml"/>
        </endpoint>
     </call>
     <property expression="fn:concat('consolidated-', get-property('SYSTEM_DATE', 'yyyy-MM-dd'),'.xml')"
               name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName"
               scope="transport"/>
     <log level="custom">
        <property name="Step 1" value="---------Writing response to file ---------"/>
     </log>
     <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED"
               scope="axis2"
               type="STRING"
               value="true"/>
     <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
     <call>
        <endpoint>
           <address uri="vfs:file://C:/output"/>
        </endpoint>
     </call>
     <log level="custom">
        <property name="Step 2" value="---------Service is called ---------"/>
     </log>
     <property expression="fn:concat('treasury-',get-property('SYSTEM_DATE', 'yyyy-MM-dd'), '.xml' )"
               name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName"
               scope="transport"/>
     <log level="custom">
        <property name="Step 2"
                  value="---------sending request to treasure site ---------"/>
     </log>
     <call>
        <endpoint>
           <address format="soap11" uri="https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/sdn.xml"/>
        </endpoint>
     </call>
     <log level="custom">
        <property name="Step 2" value="---------Writing response to file ---------"/>
     </log>
     <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED"
               scope="axis2"
               type="STRING"
               value="true"/>
     <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
     <call>
        <endpoint>
           <address uri="vfs:file://C:/output"/>
        </endpoint>
     </call>
enter code here
```

[WSO2 ESB: How to download a file over HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874928/wso2-esb-how-to-download-a-file-over-http)

Im trying to calling multiple endpoint to receive response which is supposed to be saved in this folder `file://C:/output`

Regards

Comment: Can you include the Error you receive with VFS in here.

Comment: Unable to configure the service adownload for the VFS transport: Cannot find parameter 'transport.vfs.ContentType' for service 'adownload'. This service is being marked as faulty and will not be available over the VFS transport.

Comment: please share your code, right now there is not enough information to help solve your problem

Comment: i edited with my code, i made it work , but now i cant call 2 endpoints 
other file replaced with same response of first endpoint?

Comment: As far as I understand from the above description is that the response from the first endpoint call is used for the other calls in the same mediation. This is the expected behavior because the message context is replaced with the content of the first response. The content of the message context is used for the subsequent mediation including the call mediator. If you want to preserve the content you can use a clone mediator or else you can use clone mediator depending on your use case

Comment: yes you are right, it is replaced by first response message,
How to use clone mediator in this situation

Comment: How you change your code to save file on server?